# Index fragmentation increasing too fast?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

a specific index I have is increasing its fragmentation to 50% in a single day.
The table holds logs of an SMS message request.
schema -

```
RequestId(int), primary key, auto increment
ProviderRequestId(nvarchar(350)), nullable
RelationField1 (int)
RelationField2 (int)
RelationField3 (int)
RelationField4 (int)
....
```

The index - Nonclustered index on `ProviderRequestId`. (no included columns)

The process that causes the fragmentation growth -

In order to make the request, I must send the `RequestId` generated to the provider.
Afterwards, he responds with his `ProviderRequestId`.
So I first insert a request with a NULL value in `ProviderRequestId`.
When the provider responds I update the inserted row, by the `RequestId` with the received `ProviderRequestId`.

The process above can happen a million times a day sometimes in parallel, so basically, millions of rows are being inserted into the table with a NULL value and then updated. I'm guessing that's the reason why fragmentation is growing that fast.
Afterwards multiple and fast required reads gonna happen on the `RequestId` that is initially sent to the provider, which is why I opt into using the clustered index that requires me to insert the row before receiving a response from the provider.

How would you solve that?
Should I simply run my index optimization script once a day? (https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)
Or that is bad practice and I should just instead create another integer column and manage its value in the code so I can send the request to the provider before inserting the row? which will spare all the updates I mentioned above.
But will require an additional index and probably won't be as efficient as using the clustered index for reads.

Would love to hear your thoughts, thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com. My thoughts for your question: I suppose that `ProviderRequestId` comes randomly, so a) you're correct that you need to defragment index periodically, b) take a look at PAD_INDEX and FILLFACTOR for this index.

Comment: If you don't need the non-`NULL`s from the index, you could remove them with a filtered index `WHERE ProviderRequestId IS NULL`. That may cut down the amount of fragmentation

Comment: @AlexYu as the fast growth of the fragmentation periodically means daily, isn't that too much? I'll look into PAD_INDEX and FILLFACTOR ty!

Comment: @Charlieface WUT, I can index only the nonNULL rows?! that literally sounds perfect! googling that now, ty!

Comment: That would be the opposite: `WHERE ProviderRequestId IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Charlieface and that basically means that if I insert a row with a null value in ProviderRequestId it wont be added to the index, but when I update and set a value it will? so no updates to the actual index -> no growth of fragmentation . right?

Comment: Depends if you modify it again, but non-null random inserts will also cause fragmentation, maybe not as much

Comment: No, I only modify it once from null into a random value. And yeah obviously it will also cause fragmentation but my hope is that it won't be as fast so I can schedule a script maintenance once a week instead of once a day lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragmentation is natural and expected for random key value inserts. As to whether it's actually a performance concern depends on your infrastructure. It used to be a big deal back in the day of spinning media and limited memory. Fragmentation is less of a concern on modern infrastructure.

You could specify an index fill factor to reserve free space to reduce page splits and associated fragmentation. An appropriate fill factor value is roughly the percent of new rows between scheduled reorgs (e.g. 5% if you reorg daily and insert 5M new rows in a 100M row table).

Comment: Looks like given the amount of changes to the key column, it's really deletions and re-insertions that's the problem

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if the fragmentation is happening due to the random key value inserts, or because of the NULL inserts follows by an update that triggers the deletions and re-insertions of the index as you mentioned.
I'm googling the filtered index Charlie advised, and if needed it will only add the column to the index once I update its value from null I'll know for sure as I'll take that off the equation.
Thanks guys

Comment: @Charlieface, the filtered index may help but I suspect it's the non-null values that cause the fragmentation.

Comment: @DanGuzman if most of the issue is indeed because of the nature of the random key index.
How would you decide whether to do a daily reorg/rebuild or weekly? and by that to choose the fill factor. thx

Comment: @Ben, you can run Ola's index maintenance script daily and it will reorg/rebuild only when above the configured thresholds. Personally, I would use daily insert percent as the fill factor like I mentioned in my answer. You could use a higher one so that reorg/rebuilds occur less often but with the tradeoff of more unused space.

Comment: @Ben part of your decision matrix should be whether you need to defragment at all. You're going to do all this work daily, cleaning up after something, and that may not gain you anything at all. Instead of focusing on the fragmentation % number (it's just a number!), focus on something real: the performance of the queries against this table, and whether that performance gets worse as fragmentation goes up, or improves at all right after you reorg. While I'm a fan of fragmentation for different reasons (minimizing memory footprint), a lot of people do this work blindly for little to no benefit.

Comment: @Ben I'll repeat that I do favor fragmentation on servers that are very sensitive to memory consumption and/or have weak underlying I/O subsystems. But in general and on modern hardware with sufficient memory I align with Brent Ozar's thinking: [just stop worrying about that number unless you actually see it cause problems](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/). You're going to do that work every day forever, fixing millions of slightly misaligned rows, when you may not be experiencing any negative impact. And if you are, increasing memory fixes it once.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for that comment, I have no actual performance issue with the table, but the size of the indexes reduces my free memory by a lot to about 600MB, while rebuilding/organizing the indexes bumped it up to 1.3GB.
I have some "server is not responding" errors while connecting to the RDS, which by AWS assumption was due to low free-memory value.
I've adjusted my index to filtered and I will runn Ola's index maintenance daily. hopefully those two actions will be enough. thx

Comment: I'll also set the fill factor to 95% and enable pad-index, as I insert about 5% daily

Comment: @Ben right, but that was kind of my point. You are going to do this work _forever_ due to low memory on a VM where you could easily just increase the memory _once_ and probably not even think about this again until your data grows exponentially. It's at least worth an experiment, maybe your budget is $0 but if you are paying for actual compute in any way that defragmentation operation you repeat every night isn't free either, nor is the effort you've already spent and will continue to spend managing indexes and jobs. Also, pretty sure my USB-C dock has more than 1.3GB of memory.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Makes sense, I checked, and increasing my instance memory from 16GB to 32GB is $400 a month, which is not that much, to be honest.
We might just do that anyway, to have more room to breathe, but that's probably still worthwhile doing the adjustments mentioned above isn't it? 
Daily index maintenance
and lowering the fill-factor of the random problematic index

Comment: @Ben I can't make that call for you. I can't imagine a scenario where that bubbles up to the most important performance problem to solve if you have adequate memory...